# SQL server exclude anything but a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

is their a way to exclude results pulled in a query that start with anything but a number. Exclude anytXing starting in a letter.

I tried

```
 Where a.value like '0%'
       And a.value  like '1%'
       And a.value like '2%' 
         .......3-9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select a.value
from yourtable a
where a.value like '[0-9]%'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94b07/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will work if you just change your `And`s to `Or`s.  You can also shorten your query using sql-server's pattern-matching syntax:

```
like '[0-9]%'
```